# OpenCart 3 not showing my module

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

I'm fairly new to OpenCart but I know PHP and MVC platforms. I want to make an importer for OpenCart to import some products from a CSV and the photos for them.

However, I've been struggling for the last 2 hours trying to see my module in the admin. I created an `admin/controller/module/custom_importer.php`:

```
<?php
class ControllerModuleCustomImporter extends Controller {

}
```

and a language file `admin/language/en-gb/module/custom_importer.php`:

```
$_['heading_title'] = 'Custom Importer';
```

However, in my admin I can't seem to find the module at all. It's the simplest, emptiest module. What am I doing wrong?

*Opencart: Version 3.0.2.0*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path you are using is wrong.  Put your file in `admin/controller/extension/module/custom_importer.php`.  Note the class name changes in a corresponding way.

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleCustomImporter extends Controller {

}
```

The language file goes in `admin/language/en-gb/extension/module/custom_importer.php`.

```
<?php
$_['heading_title'] = 'Custom Importer';
```

Now go to Extensions->Extensions and choose Modules.  You will see Custom Importer.

Comment: And, another question: how would I go about adding a link to that page in the admin menu?

Comment: Please open a new question.